# All files are parsed as PHP after rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website located at example.com.
I've built a Laravel-based CMS for managing small sites and now try to set up rewriting.

In the root directory my .htaccess has:

```
RewriteRule ^(lorem|ipsum)/?(.*) cms/public/$2 [L,PT]
```

because I want to rewrite example.com/lorem and example.com/ipsum to my CMS. This works fine, but then I have another .htaccess in cms/public/:

```
RewriteRule assets/(.*) assets/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

That's because I want to have cms/public/assets/ available from `example.com/lorem/any/location/assets/file.css` and redirect everything else to index.php.

Seems to work, however I've noticed that all files, including images, are served as `text/html` and PHP code is executed even in non-PHP files. Why is that happening and how to fix it?

Comment: If you comment out above rules do you see any change in this behavior?

Comment: That's clever. I've located the problem, it was misapplied .htaccess line for changing PHP version, not mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, rewriting was not to blame. I put `Use php54` into cms/.htaccess and this line should've been preceded by `:Location *.php`. After adding it everything works perfectly.